# How I can calculate $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n + 1)}{n^2 + 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I turned a series into the integral 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(\log x)}{x^2 + 1}dx
$$
using partial fractions and other techniques, but I don't know what to do next. 
I did a search on the site but found nothing similar. Thus, 
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n + 1)}{n^2 + 1} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(\log x)}{x^2 + 1}dx = ?
$$

Comment: My initial guess would be that complex analysis on the function $f(z) = \csc(\pi z) \frac{2z+1}{z^2+1}$ should relate the sum to the residues at $z = \pm i$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(-1)%5En(2n%2B1)%2F(n%5E2%2B1)+n+from+0+to+infinity&t=crmtb01) just gives an expression in terms of special values of the digamma function.

Comment: @Mathsource: the numerical value of the series is $\approx 0.0967935$ while $\frac{\pi}{4\cosh(\pi/2)}\approx 0.313$ (this is the value of the integral. The integral *does not* equal the series.)

Comment: It's easy to see that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(\log x)}{x^2 + 1}dx=\frac12 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\log x)}{x^2 + 1}dx$, afterwards the integral becomes a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136232/how-to-evaluate-pv-int-0-infty-frac-cos-ln-xx21-dx

Comment: Since the integral is not equal to the series, which of them do you want to find? I think, since the integral is already given in the link provided by Zacky, you might be interested in the series instead?

Comment: The numerical value for the series is `0.096793522075048617872128356531876940020355002729814...` and indeed, nothing better than a few digamma functions of complex argument can be given as a closed form

Comment: Using generating functions, the series can be represented as  $$
f(x) =\frac i 2·\left(x^{-i}·∫{\frac{x^{-1 + i}·(x + 1)}{(x - 1)^2} dx} - x^i·∫{\frac{x^{-1 - i}·(x + 1)}{(x - 1)^2}dx}\right)
$$ at $x=-1$

Comment: Using [Euler's transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) and the help of Mathematica, I have obtained a curious accelerated series:

$$S=\frac{1}{4} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \left[(2+i) B(n+1,i)+(2-i) B(n+1,-i) \right]$$ Where B is naturally the Beta function

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342365/is-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-1-nn21-related-to-any-popular-const

Comment: Hypergeometric form of the series $$S= {_4 F_3} \left( 1, \frac32, i,-i; \frac12, 1-i,1+i;-1 \right)$$